# Como afectar a otro elemento al hacer focus en un textarea

Tags: html, css

me gustaría cambiar cambiar el color del label al hacer foco en el textarea, pero no consigo hacerlo, actualmente utilizo las siguientes líneas en CSS

```
<div class="col-12">
    <label class="label-admin" for="comentarioOpcional">Comentario Opcional</label>
    <textarea class="form-control textarea-admin" name="comentarioOpcional" id="comentarioOpcional" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>

.textarea-admin{
      resize: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;  
      border: none;
      border-bottom: solid 3px #AEAEAE;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
      /* transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.64,.09,.08,1);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 99%, #B91817 1%);
      background-position: -100vw 0;
      background-size: auto 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; */
}
.textarea-admin:hover ~ .label-admin{
    color: aqua important;  
}
```

Estaría agradecido de su ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera usando javascript

Agregue los eventos `onfocus="changeLabelBgColor()"`  y   `onblur="restoreLabelBgColor()"` al tag `<textarea>` y en el script se realiza el cambio de color.

```css
.textarea-admin{
      resize: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;  
      border: none;
      border-bottom: solid 3px #AEAEAE;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
      /* transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.64,.09,.08,1);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 99%, #B91817 1%);
      background-position: -100vw 0;
      background-size: auto 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; */
}
.textarea-admin:hover ~ .label-admin{
    color: aqua important;  
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
    <label class="label-admin"  for="comentarioOpcional">Comentario Opcional</label>
    <textarea class="form-control textarea-admin" onfocus="changeLabelBgColor()" onblur="restoreLabelBgColor()" name="comentarioOpcional" id="comentarioOpcional" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
const label = document.querySelector(".label-admin")

function changeLabelBgColor(){
  label.style.backgroundColor = "#05d" //CAMBIAR EL COLOR QUE DESEA
}

function restoreLabelBgColor(){
  label.style.backgroundColor = ""
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto no se puede solo con CSS. si estás usando jQuery, te ayudo con eso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".form-control").on("mouseover",function(){
  $(".label-admin").css({"color": "red"})
 });
 
 $(".form-control").on("mouseleave",function(){
  $(".label-admin").css({"color": "inherit"})
 })

)};
```

Esta función solo hover. Pero si prefieres que no sea así, se puede cambiar **mouseover** por **click**.
Y una cosa más: en tu CSS te faltó el signo: **!** Así:

```
color: aqua !important;
```